# Interrogative in relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, interrogatives

I wrote:

> However, the program needs a feature training file, (feat.trn), **which** I don't know **what it is**, and how I can provide **it**.

I know in relative clauses wh-words are used as the absent pronoun like:

> He gave me the book which I like.
>
> ** He gave me the book which I like  <s>it</s> .

But in my sentence I used "it" in the relative clause, is my sentence yet correct?

Comment: You really don't need the comma before the opening parenthesis... it makes no sense there.

Comment: +1. The *it* in your first example is called a "resumptive pronoun"; you may be interested in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun. As explained there, they're pretty common in sentences like your first one, but not usually considered "correct". (And not just by peevers. Even ordinary speakers find them weird, but we resort to them when we get too far into a sentence that won't work without one.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's second example correctly shows that we don't like to simultaneously reference *the book* using both ***which*** and ***it*** in the same relative clause.

This makes things awkward for the first case, where we need to reference *a feature training file* twice in the relative clause (*within which* there are two embedded [free relative clauses](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Free-Relative-Clause.htm)). Sometimes native speakers will simply ignore the above principle, but the end result always tends to sound uneducated/careless.

Most speakers would simply abandon the relative clause construction and switch to a constrastive conjunction (which could be one sentence or two - the punctuation is a stylistic choice)...

> *The program needs a feature training file, **but** I don't know what it is, or how I can provide it.*

Comment: +1 Technically, the embedded free relative clauses *what **it** is* and *how I can provide **it*** are ["extraction islands"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Wh-islands)--specifically, "*wh-* islands": entities inside them, like the *its* I have boldfaced,  cannot be replaced with, first, a relative pronoun (*which*), and then the gap or trace left when the relative is fronted.

Comment: @StoneyB: I hadn't consciously recognized that "embedded" aspect, but I'm sure it's central to the reason we don't like using ***it*** to reference the same object as that originally introduced by ***which/that*** as the first element in a relative clause. But we're dealing with a rule ***which it's*** not hard to see has fuzzy edges.

Comment: "What it is" and "how I can provide it" are not relatives; they are subordinate interrogative clauses.

Comment: @BillJ: I'm not going to get hung up about terminology here. The important thing is ***it*** in OP's example appears within ***embedded*** clauses, and I'm sure that relates to why we don't like it. For most purposes, when ***which/that*** serve as relative pronouns introducing a relative clause, we expect it to be in the role of ***subject***, so we expect the next word to be a ***verb***. But I can't help feeling there's some uncertainty about exactly which forms are acceptable, and which aren't.

Comment: In "He gave me the book which I like __, gap is direct object and co-referenced to "which" and the antecedent "book". Expressing "it" overtly in the relative clause is thus inserting the direct object twice; that's why it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **what it is** is the correct order, not **what is it**. But the oddness comes from another thing. Consider this sentence **I don't know what it is**. If we want to add **the file** in that sentence, it won't fit in. And that's why we can't say **which I don't know what it is**. That **which** refers back to **that particular file**.

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, but that just a "toy" example where the solution is simply not to include ***it*** (what's "left" is still perfectly grammatical).

Comment: @Man_From_India: You're quite right. I don't know what prompted me to reverse OP's original (correct) sequence. Fixed, ty.

Comment: It's not a 'toy' example, whatever is meant by that.It's the OP's actual example. The simple fact is that the relativised element "which" is direct object, which is why including "it" is effectively expressing the direct object twice.

Comment: And about the terminology, I completely agree with @BillJ.

Comment: @Man_From_India: I'm certainly not going to take sides between you, BillJ, and StoneyB on the terminology. But it's worth noting that native speakers can and do sometimes "ignore the above principle" (whatever "rule" says OP's construction is ungrammatical). My guess is this is partly because the principle is a bit fuzzy, and partly because it can be very difficult to rephrase to avoid problems, if simply "discarding" ***it*** isn't enough. Also consider *He called me an idiot, which **it** wasn't wise to do*. Personally, I'm happy with that regardless of whether ***it*** is present or not.

Comment: @BillJ There are competing terminologies here: these *wh-* nominals are variously called 'embedded questions', 'embedded interrogative clauses', 'free relative clauses', 'fused relative clauses', and all of these terms have different inadequacies.But whatever you call em, you can't 'extract' a term into a superordinate *wh-* and leave a gap behind AND you can't extract into the *wh-* and leave a pro-form behind. It's a lose/lose situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, it's true that it's a bit hard to distinguish *a fused relative clause* and *an open interrogative embedded clause* in some cases. *He called me an idiot, which **it** wasn't wise to do.* - I thought this is ungrammatical.

Comment: @StoneyM Surprised you said that. A fused (aka "free", "nominal") relative clause and an (embedded) interrogative clause are entirely different constructions and are used for quite different purposes, the former being a modifying clause in NP structure and the latter an interrogative complement clause. Gapping in relatives to represent a 'missing' element is standard stuff really.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thinking about *He called me an idiot, which **it** wasn't wise to do.*, I think I was wrong about this sentence. It's correct regardless of whether we use **it** there or not.

Comment: @Man_From_India: Okay, consider [A 'system of interest' in the context of this book is any urban or regional system which **it** is useful to study.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22system+which+it+is+useful+to%22) Things start getting *really* fuzzy there for me (probably because it's a bit uncertain whether ***it*** specifically refers to "any system", or is just the "existential **it**").

Comment: @Stoney M In, for example, the fused relative "I've eaten what you gave me", the meaning is "I've eaten the thing that you gave me". In the subordinate interrogative "I told her what it was", the meaning is "I told her the answer to the question 'What was it?'".

Comment: @BillJ Among those who use the term, *free/fused relatives* are contrasted with the *bound relatives* used as "modifying" clauses; *CamGEL* further distinguishes FRs from EQ (I'm not clear on what basis or why) In any case, these are all the same construction, with different uses. It's the straight interrogative which is differently constructed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Let's consider your example sentence - *He called me an idiot, which **it** wasn't wise to do.*. This **it** is a dummy pronoun. I see it this way. When there is no **it** there, the whole thing of calling me an idiot comes as a subject of the sentence - *X wasn't wise to do*. When there is **it**, it's just a dummy. *It wasn't wise to do (pro-form of **call**) [me an idiot]*.

Comment: @BillJ The key thing seems to me to be that the identical construction can serve as either an "EQ" or an "FR": *He asked me what I wanted*, *I ate what I wanted*.

Comment: @Stoney B Well, in _I've eaten what you gave me_, "what you gave me" is a noun phrase whose head is 'fused' with the first element in the relative clause. By contrast, in _I told her what it was_, the element "what is was" is a clause, not an NP.

Comment: @Man_From_India: Exactly! In *some* contexts where ***it*** is just a "dummy" we can simply remove it and be left with a totally different syntactic construction that's still grammatical *and* has *exactly the same meaning*. But in other contexts, such as *He gave me this coin, which **it** seems **is** counterfeit*, we'd have to remove ***is*** as well to maintain grammaticality. And in some contexts the sentence requires so many changes to make it grammatical that people just give up and allow a "deliberate" error to come out.

Comment: ...note that this issue [was raised on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245363/) (Killick in the movie *Master and Commander* often uses a form we'd generally consider "ungrammatical"), but it didn't attract much interest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the link. I will see it later. Too tired today :( see you.

Comment: _He gave me this coin which it seems is counterfeit_, is okay. The sequence "it seems" is just an adjunct, parenthetical and omissible with "it" is a dummy subject pronoun. It has no effect on the underlying relative clause which is still _He gave me this coin which is counterfeit_. Cf. _He gave me this coin which is counterfeit, it seems_.

Comment: @BillJ: Not so. As I pointed out, if you discard ***it*** you have to *also* discard ***is*** to maintain grammaticality ***and*** preserve the meaning. You can't say that converting to *He gave me this coin which is counterfeit* has no effect on the meaning, because *that* version asserts the coin really ***is*** counterfeit (rather than simply *appearing* to be so).

Comment: I discarded "it + seems" since it is an adjunct and parenthetical. "It belongs with "seems"; "it" is the subject of the clause "it seems", so "it" + "seems" are inseparable. The dummy pronoun "it" has nothing at all to do with the internal syntax of the relative clause. You can of course say _He gave me this coin which seems counterfeit_. which has the same meaning, but I'm talking about the example you gave 3 messages back!

Comment: @BillJ: Since I'm perfectly fluent in English, but don't necessarily know the precise terminology appropriate to the constructions being discussed here, I'm simply trying to convey to *learners* that "the rules" in this specific context are complicated ***and/or*** inconsistently applied. If you can find a short clear-cut way of defining exactly how to distinguish "valid" from "invalid" usages, I'll be the first to upvote your answer. But the truth is native speakers *do* sometimes play fast and loose with such constructions, because ***sometimes it's difficult not to***.

Comment: Having read all the comments, I now know considerably less than I thought I did when I began reading them. It seems to me, though, that the dummy **it** nearly always confuses more than it clarifies, and that its every use can be avoided if a modicum of care is given to the construction of the sentence. Can't we just banish the confounded thing?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The Wikipedia article about this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun, may help you gather some of the terminology you need.

Answer (score 3):

> *However, the program needs a feature training file, (feat.trn), which
>   I don't know what is it, and how I can provide it.

If you don't want to use **yet** or **but** etc:

> However, the program needs a feature training file, which *is
>   something* I don't know about and don't know how to provide.
>
> However, the program needs a feature training file, which *is
>   something* unknown to me, which I don't know how to provide.

P.S.

> However, the program needs a feature training file, something (that) I don't know about and don't know how to provide.
>
> However, the program needs a feature training file, something I know nothing about and don't know how to provide.
>
> However, the program needs a feature training file, something unknown to me and I don't know how to provide it.

Comment: Thank you! how about "The program needs a feature training file, something that I don't know about and don't know how to provide."

Comment: Indeed.  **something** can head the clause in that way. See the P.S.